# Xamarin.Forms TcpClient TtlExpired

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tcpclient

I'm using

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(); 
await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Text, Convert.ToInt32(Port.Text));
```

Then `client.Connected` is `True` but when I ping server

```
Ping p = new Ping(); 
PingReply reply = p.Send(IPAddress.Text, 3000);
```

I get status: `TtlExpired`

do you have any ideas what could be wrong?
thanx

Answer (score 0):

[Ttl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingoptions.ttl?view=netframework-4.7.2)  specifies the number of times the Ping data packets can be forwarded. The default value is 128, so this error means, the packet has not reached its destination after being forwarded 128 times (in the gateways/routers).

> Use the Ttl property to specify the maximum number of times the ICMP echo message can be forwarded before reaching its destination. If the packet does not reach its destination after being forwarded the specified number of times, the packet is discarded and the ICMP echo request fails. When this happens, the Status is set to TtlExpired.

So use the `Ping.Send` overload that accepts a `PingOptions`, and set a bigger `Ttl` value in the `PingOptions`.

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();

// Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);

// Wait 10 seconds for a reply.
int timeout = 10000;

// Set options for transmission:
// The data can go through 255 gateways or routers
// before it is destroyed, and the data packet
// cannot be fragmented.
PingOptions options = new PingOptions (255, true);

// Send the request.
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(IPAddress.Text, timeout, buffer, options);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you ping the host in cmd?

Comment: yea, console:    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss) ... I dont understatnd whats going on

Comment: And what is the value of Ttl in console?

Comment: Pinging 10.111.250.210 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.111.250.210: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127